# Extract values from a dataframe according to identifiers of a list of list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have a to extract values in a data frame and to assign them to identifiers of a list of list. Example:

Inupt1: **BR** is my list of lists that looks as follow

```
$BR_1
[1] "id5"  "id6"  "id7"  "id8"  "id9"  "id10"

$BR_2
[1] "id13" "id14" "id15" "id16" "id17" "id18" "id19"
```

Input2: **DF** is my data frame that looks like this:

```
Ids      Value 
id1      0
id2      0
id3      0
id4      0
id5      1
id6      1
id7      1
id8      1
id9      2
id10     2
id11     0
id12     0
id13     1
id14     2
id15     3
id16     3
id17     3
id18     2
id19     1
id20     0
```

Desired Output:

```
BR_1 (1,1,1,1,2,2)  BR_2 (1,2,3,3,3,2,1)
```

Then from these output i need to take only those that do not have the maximum score of 3 (then only BR_1).

Sorry if I am a bit not correct with the terminology. Any idea is very appreciated.

Comment: `lapply(BR, function(i) DF$Value[match(i, DF$Ids)])` should do it

Comment: Thanks Sotos, and lets say I want to select only the BR with values lower than 3? Is it possible to create a list constraining only those with values < 3? In this case i would like to retain only BR_1. Thanks again! p.s. consider that i have millions of these lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [Sotos'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580/sotos) idea using `lapply` function.

You can create a subset with all values lower than 3:

```
newDF = subset(DF, Value <3)
lapply(BR, function(x) newDF[match(x, newDF$Ids),"Value"])
```

Or you can modify your result list:

```
raw = lapply(BR, function(x) newDF[match(x, newDF$Ids),"Value"])
result = raw[sapply(raw, max) < 3]
```

Comment: second solution is the most appropriate. I also went through the tutorial of sapply thanks.